# How can I get request.el to return data directly?

Tags: url

I know how to use request.el to get data and insert it into a buffer, but what if I want to simply have request.el return the data itself (e.g., for saving in a variable)?

Here's my attempt, but this doesn't actually return data (in this case a small amount of test JSON):

```
(request "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
:parser 'json-read
:success (cl-function
      (lambda (&key data &allow-other-keys)
    data))))
```

Comment: How about something like this?:  `(let* ((buf (url-retrieve-synchronously "https://api.github.com/users/lawlist/gists")) (str (with-current-buffer buf (buffer-string)))) (kill-buffer buf) str)`

Comment: That would absolutely work, but I'm hoping to use request.el for this because it can create more complex url requests.

Comment: The doc-string for `parser` states in part:  "*So, for example, you can pass `json-read` to parse JSON object in the buffer.  To fetch whole response as a
string, pass `buffer-string`.*"  Have a look at the doc-string for other clues and perhaps try using `buffer-string` as suggested ...  I don't have that particular library installed at the moment, and merely git cloned it to see what makes it tick ...  https://github.com/tkf/emacs-request/blob/master/request.el#L439

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for this I think:

```
(request-response-data
 (request "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
   :parser 'json-read
   :sync t))
```

the :sync arg avoids the need for a callback I think by making it wait for the request to be done.

Comment: Perfect---thank you!